# Is it normal for Firebase A/B testing variant to keep changing on re-fetch?

Tags: android, firebase-ab-testing

I have a Firebase A/B experiment running on Android,
Experiment is based on a Remote config that has [A, B] values,
What is weird is that sometimes when I fetch the value again from firebase I get a different one,
for example first time I get "A" then third time it's "B" is this normal?
like am I supposed to store the first value I get?